# X Not Starting in VMWare After NVidia Driver Installed

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, xorg, vmware

So I have an Ubuntu Gnome boot partition on a physical drive on my system that is working as expected when using it on its own.

I also configured VMWare in another OS on another drive to point to and boot the physical device on which Ubuntu resides.

This worked fine using the vmware gfx driver for the VM and the nouveau driver otherwise. However, after replacing nouveau with the nvidia-390 driver, I can now no longer get X/GDM to start when booting in VMWare.
It appears to be related to X being unable to load the GLX extension using the vmware driver.

Any way that I can get this configuration working again?

Here's the relevant output of lspci in VM:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter
```

And with the system running on the hardware itself:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
65:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b06 (rev a1)
```

Here's my Xorg.log from the VM: [Xorg.log](https://my.mixtape.moe/nhttlm.log)

Answer (score 1):

**You should be very careful trying to mix a legitimate Dual Boot environment with a VM environment.**  VMware actually makes a note in their documentation that this can sometimes lead to 'undefined behavior' in the guest VMs and lead to other problems.  In fact, they try very hard to dissuade people from doing what you're trying.

You should pick one type of setup, or the other:

- Virtual Machine
- Dual Boot

Sticking to one or the other will help to protect you from having to install two sets of drivers and help stop your system from having multiple incompatible driver sets installed and running simultaneously.

You should really only be doing a Dual Boot, or a VM, and not mix-and-match the two together - it causes undefined behavior and driver conflicts like this one.

---

> Original content of the "Remove the nVidia drivers from the VM" answer is [available here](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1026429/1).

Comment: I need the nvidia driver for when I boot the ubuntu system itself. Not sure if I made it clear in the original post, but my VM points at a physical drive on my system that I use to dual boot. I also have the VM gfx drivers installed, but I'm trying to get them to coexist.

Comment: @BlaiseRitchie I'm confused - is Ubuntu inside a VM, or installed as a dual boot with your Windows OS on the computer itself?  You ***only*** can use the nVidia drivers if it's in a dual boot with the Windows OS.  The VM otherwise ***doesn't see*** an nVidia card, and having them on the VM is pointless at that point.  Why do you need the nVidia graphics driver on the VM if the VM is ***never going to see the nVidia card***?

Comment: Ubuntu is installed on a partition on an SSD. I can dual boot into it fine and load the nVidia drivers and start gdm3/X/Gnome. However, in my Windows dual boot, I created a VMWare VM but instead of a virtual hard disk file, I have VMWare using the physical disk on which my Ubuntu dual boot resides. I can't start X in the VM mode after switching from nouveau to nVidia in dual boot mode.

Comment: @BlaiseRitchie I should point out that VMware makes a note that doing that can be 'dangerous' for unspecified reasons.  You need to update your question to make a note about this.  But you can't install the nVidia drivers and have them as 'active' if the VMware driver(s) are also active - it causes some incompatibilities.  Either stick to this being a full VM or stick to the DualBoot.  Don't try and mix dualboot and VM boot, it introduces issues such as these you're seeing.